# Android TextInputLayout/EditText is not full size and cuts off text

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I have a fragment which contains a calculator (Just three TextInputEditTexts which listen for input).

These inputs are set out in a RelativeLayout as shown below-

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/binomial_probability_wrapper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/label_probability"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp">
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/binomial_probability_input"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/binomial_trials_wrapper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/label_trials"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/binomial_probability_wrapper">
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/binomial_trials_input"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:inputType="numberSigned"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/binomial_successes_wrapper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/label_successes"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/binomial_trials_wrapper">
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/binomial_successes_input"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:inputType="numberSigned"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have also tried using a LinearLayout with each input on a separate row, but that had the same result.

As you can see in this image-
[image]

the bottom input is cut off. If I measure it on my screen it is clearly a different size, but Android returns the same value for the heights of each layout and input.

Any suggestions as to how to fix this are welcome.

Edit: Some extra information. The layout bounds show that the text cursor is actually taller than the height of the bottom TextInputEditText. The top have the correct height.

Second edit: I added the a TextView below (For output) and that is now cut off, while the TextInputEditText is now the same as the others.

Comment: change `RelativeLayout`'s width from `fill_parent` to `match_parent`?

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't change anything. It seems that whatever view I have at the bottom of layout is cut off. The only way I have found (so far) to fix the problem is to add a View with a minimum height to act as some sort of padding.

Comment: what if you change your text size/amount of padding? You might just have too much information.

Comment: If I change the padding of the view, the view just gets overlapped by the whitespace for some reason, the same goes for adding a margin to the view. Setting minHeight works.

Answer (score 8):

As saying in official github page:

> `TextInputLayout` provides two height variations for filled and outline
>   text fields, standard and dense. Both box styles default to the
>   standard height.
>
> In order to reduce the height of a text box, you can use a dense
>   style, which will reduce the vertical padding within the text box. You
>   can achieve this by applying the appropriate styles to your
>   `TextInputLayout` and `TextInputEditText`, depending on whether you are
>   using a filled or outline text field

So try to apply `@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.Dense` to your `TextInputLayout` or change padding for `TextInputEditText`

Comment: It is the correct answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
  <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/binomial_probability_wrapper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/label_probability"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp">
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/binomial_probability_input"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

You have to use  android:paddingTop="5dp" in

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/binomial_probability_wrapper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/label_probability"
        android:paddingTop="5dp">
 ---- write something ----
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```