# Why my TextInputLayout always cuts off upper hint text in Android?

Tags: android, xml, android-textinputlayout

I'm implementing `EditText` with in `TextInputLayout` with style `TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense`. Whenever I got focus edit text my hint floats up but it always been cut off from upper side like [image: this].

I've searched [Android TextInputLayout/EditText is not full size and cuts off text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38440516/android-textinputlayout-edittext-is-not-full-size-and-cuts-off-text), [android TextInputLayout changes EditText style after setting error to null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34182435/android-textinputlayout-changes-edittext-style-after-setting-error-to-null) and many more on stack overflow. Also  but applying paddings, margins but from no one I got solution.

> here's xml

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                style="@style/LoginTextInputLayoutStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/textInputLayout_layout_margin"
                android:hint="Owner ID"
                android:theme="@style/LoginTextInputLayoutStyle"
                >

                <EditText

                    android:id="@+id/addUser_ownerID"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/textInputLayout_ed_margin_left"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/neo_sans_std"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/textInputLayout_ed_textSize" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

> theme for TextInputLayout

```
<style name="LoginTextInputLayoutStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense">
        <item name="boxStrokeColor">@color/colorYellow</item>
        <item name="boxStrokeWidth">@dimen/_1sdp</item>
```

Comment: I think this is due to the custom font you are using, try using default

Comment: @LakhwinderSingh - Thx for the comment. I got your point and i got my answer but what if I shall want to use custom font ?

Comment: does the font changing solves the issue?

Comment: yeah, it solved!

Comment: OK, Try another custom font, maybe the font is the issue

Comment: Use a TextInputEditText instead of a EditText

Comment: You're right. It's font's issue.

Comment: I am also facing same issue due to custom font. Did anyone has solution?

Comment: @BhaveshHirpara - Just change your font style.

Comment: @IrfanAkram I can not change font file as it's requirement from client. Any solution if I use that font?

Comment: Unfortunately, No solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `android:includeFontPadding="false"` on the EditText to ignore font padding, it is `true` by default. Also you should rather use `com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText` instead of EditText, because that's the proper Material UI component to be used with TextInputLayout.